# Using Functions to Converting miles to kilometers

Tags: python

This function converts miles to kilometers (km). Complete the function by having it return the result, then call the function to convert 55 miles, and print "The distance in kilometers is " with the result of the function. Then calculate the round-trip in kilometers by doubling it, and print "The round-trip in kilometers is " with that number.

so far my code looks like this:

```
def convert_distance(miles):
km = miles * 1.6  # approximately 1.6 km in 1 mile
return km
miles = (55)    
km = convert_distance(miles)
print("The distance in kilometers is: " + str(km))
print("The round-trip in kilometers is: " + str(km * 2))
```

Anytime i try submitting it gives me this message pops-up:
Not quite. Remember to use the str() function to convert
numbers into strings when printing them with text, and to
call the function with just one parameter, then accept the
return value into a new variable.

Comment: Make sure you indent everything properly, also no need to include 55 in () when you assign, it's an number, not a tuple. `miles = 55` would work.

Comment: so whats the issue / question? your code will output 88 and 176 which is correct for `55 * 1.6` and `88 * 2`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Your code seems fine. Please [edit] to clarify what the problem is.

Comment: It looks like the *original* code did not indent anything, while an edit fixed this problem.

Comment: When properly indented your code works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def convert_distance(miles):
    km = miles * 1.6 
    return km
result = convert_distance(55)
print("The distance in Kilometers is " + str(result))
print("The round-trip in Kilometers is " + str(result*2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clarify very well which design of script is required in your task.

1. Is it just definition of function only:

   ```
   def convert_distance(miles):
       km = miles * 1.6  # approximately 1.6 km in 1 mile
       return(str(km * 2))
   ```
2. Is it definition + call of function:

   ```
   def convert_distance(miles):
       km = miles * 1.6  # approximately 1.6 km in 1 mile
       return(str(km * 2))
   convert_distance(55)
   ```
3. What is an expected output of function? Is it number only or full message:

   ```
   def convert_distance(miles):
       km = miles * 1.6  # approximately 1.6 km in 1 mile
       return(f'The distance in kilometers is: {km}\n The round-trip in kilometers is: {km * 2}')
   ```
4. Does function need to have an output? Only `print` can be required:

   ```
   def convert_distance(miles):
       km = miles * 1.6  # approximately 1.6 km in 1 mile
       print(f'The distance in kilometers is: {km}\n The round-trip in kilometers is: {km * 2}')
   ```